# Using openexchangerates API for currency conversion using JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I have managed to place JSON data into a form-control using JS which is this:

```
$("#getRates").ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json?app_id="APP_ID", function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        for (var value in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
            var text = document.createTextNode(value);
        var select = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[1];

        select.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).appendChild(text);


    }
}
```

The current JSON file only contains the countries names but I wish to use the a different JSON file which is called Latest.JSON and contains the most recent rates, but it has these fields:

"license": 
  "timestamp": 1417258840,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.672743,
    "AFN": 57.800375,

How can I just use the append the "rates" to the form-function and use the rates for the conversion?

As I have previously tried I just console.log and receive "License" "timestamp" "base" but no rates?

Not after specific answer maybe just some direction towards where to look?

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON("http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=b65b6f0a06204a6087bab9a63a5845b7", function (data) {
        console.log(data.rates);

```
    for (var key in data.rates) {
    if (data.rates.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var text = document.createTextNode(key);
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[1];



    console.log(select);

    select.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).appendChild(text);


}
}

   for (var value in data.rates) {
    if (data.rates.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        var text = document.createTextNode(value);
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[2];


 console.log(select);

    select.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).appendChild(text);


    }
}

});
});
```

I changed the var key to data.rates and this seems to of solved it.

This now populates both of my form-cotrols with the data.rates values from latest.json ..

The console.log() is just for my own usage..